# How to write a variable, which has variable index in php?

Tags: php

I have variables like $start1,$start2...$start($no_col). How can I show all the variables with echo in php? in the code below it doesn't work. $no_col can change from 1 to 10. it is not fixed! I want the result show me all $start1,$start2... $start($no_col) values. All the $start1 ..$start10 variable contain **date**  like 2022-12-10;

> 

```
        for ($i=1; $i <=$no_col ; $i++) { 
            echo $start.${$i};
```

The result will be like this:
2022-03-10 2022-09-06 ...

Comment: `echo ${'start' . $i};`

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not using an array for the values instead?

Comment: Or `echo ${"start{$i}"}`, if you don't want concatenation in the middle. But yeah, while this syntax is interesting, you can do the same thing with an array: `$starts = [1 => '2022-03-10', 2 => '2022-09-06']` (etc, or similar), then `$starts[$i]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get_defined_vars` function for get all variables, and after that show only what you need:

```
  <?php
    $start1 = 10;
    $start2 = 20;
    $start3 = 30;
    $start4 = 40;
    $start5 = 50;
    
    //get all defined vars
    $vars = get_defined_vars();
    
    foreach($vars as $var=>$val) {
        if (substr($var, 0, 5) == 'start') {
            printf('$%s = %s '. PHP_EOL, $var, $val);
        }
        
    }
```

[PHPize - online editor](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php81/61035a896ff9ca31959a7635048654d3/)